# SQL Query to update table with time dependencies

Tags: mysql, wamp

I'm running a WAMP set-up with a VBA interface for my application. This application defines "employees" and their relationship to an "organisation" via a time based relationship.

I am having troubles coming up with an efficient method for updating the tables in my database. There are 3 tables that define: employees, organisations and the relationship between and employee and the start/ finish dates of employment at that organisation.The issue arrises when an entry that spans a period needs to be split: ie the entry that origanlly defines the employee working with an organisation for 1 year is split as the employee works for another business for 1 month within this year.
I have structured my tables in the following manor:

**tbl_employee**

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | firstname | lastname |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | jordan    | bean     |
|  2 | kevin     | sams     |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

**tbl_organisation**

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | nanosoft |
|  2 | attic Gm |
+----+----------+
```

**tbl_relation_employee_organisation**

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
| id | employee_id | organisation_id | validfrom  |  validto   |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |           1 |               1 | 2015-01-01 | 2016-01-01 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

Now the problem I'm facing is updating the tbl_relation_employee_organisation table such that an employee can change organisation in between the existing extry i.e. if employee 1 was to be related to organisation 2 from ***2015-10-01*** to ***2015-11-01*** 
(perhaps my problem warrants modifying my table structure: relating the employee to an organisation with only the date the change occured?)

What query can I run on this structure to 'split' the row on the relation table in the following mannor

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
| id | employee_id | organisation_id | validfrom  |  validto   |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |           1 |               1 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-09-30 |
|  2 |           1 |               2 | 2015-10-01 | 2016-11-01 |
|  3 |           1 |               1 | 2015-11-02 | 2016-01-01 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Why not turn this into 3 rows? That is what would be accurate right? Change the validto to the start date - 1 and the new third row would start from the new row validto + 1. Also, you shouldn't tag mysql and sql-server. Which DBMS are you working with?

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect your feedback. This was my intention but my table entries were vague. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q:** What query can I run on this structure to 'split' the row on the relation table.

**A:** Given the information provided, the 'split' require *two* queries, an UPDATE of the existing row, and an INSERT to add the two new rows. For example:

```
UPDATE tbl_relation_employee_organisation t 
   SET t.validto = '2015-09-30'
 WHERE t.id = 1
```

and

```
INSERT INTO tbl_relation_employee_organization 
(id, employee_id, organisation_id, validfrom, validto)
VALUES (2, 1, 2, '2015-10-01','2015-11-01')
     , (3, 1, 1, '2015-11-02','2016-01-01')
```

That would be the most efficient (in terms of database performance) to 'split' the row.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

To get this operation performed in a single statement, if there's a UNIQUE (or PRIMARY KEY) constraint on the `id` column...

```
INSERT INTO tbl_relation_employee_organization 
(id, employee_id, organisation_id, validfrom, validto)
VALUES (1, 1, 1, '2015-01-01','2015-09-30')
     , (2, 1, 2, '2015-10-01','2015-11-01')
     , (3, 1, 1, '2015-11-02','2016-01-01')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE employee_id     = VALUES(employee_id)
     , organisation_id = VALUES(organisation_id)
     , validfrom       = VALUES(validfrom)
     , validto         = VALUES(validto)
```

Note that you would need to at least supply the `id` value of the row to be updated; if `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you could substitute `NULL` for the `id` values for the second and third rows.

Alternatively, if you have a UNIQUE constraint on `(employee_id,validfrom)`, you could omit the `id` values, and allow the DUPLICATE KEY exception to be raised by the values of those two columns, and get the UPDATE action performed, without requiring `id` values being supplied. (With this approach, the attempt to `INSERT` the duplicate row will use up an auto_increment value; that value gets consumed even if a row isn't inserted, because of the order that MySQL performs the operations (the DUPLICATE KEY exception isn't thrown until the insert is attempted, and the auto_increment value is retrieved/incremented when the attempt is made to do the insert.)

Comment: Thanks spencer, I wasnt sure if there was a method for completing this in a single query.

Comment: @JordanElphick: if you had a UNIQUE constraint `id`, you could use an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement. But the net result of that would be equivalent to running three statements: an INSERT against the existing row (id=1), which would raise a DUPLICATE KEY exception, which would then cause the UPDATE action to occur, and then an insert of the second row (id=2).

Comment: What if you do not know the id of the entry to update on the relation_employee_organisation table? i.e. if instead of updating via the id of the entry how would you update only knowing the id of the employee and the validto date.